# VBA Parameter Default Today's Date

Tags: vba, date

I'm trying to create a VBA function that has an end date parameter that will default to today's date if nothing is entered.

```
Public Function timePeriods(ByVal StartDate as Date, ByVal changeFrequency as String, _
                            Optional ByVal endDate as Date = #1/1/1900#) as Double
    If endDate = #1/1/1900# Then
        endDate = Date
    End If
    MsgBox "End Date: " & Format(endDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Select Case changeFrequency
        Case "Daily"
            timePeriods = endDate - startDate
        Case "Weekly"
            timePeriods = (endDate - startDate)/7
    End Select
End Function
```

If the default value is used, the message box shows "End Date: 12/30/1899" and the function returns a negative number.  This also happens with Now() instead of Date. If a date is specified, the calculations are correct.  How do I get today's date into endDate?

Comment: If I assign endDate = Date then pass that as the parameter, today's date is passed.  I cannot seem to assign today's date inside the function.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. `Debug.Print timePeriods(Date - 10, "Daily")` produces a message box with "End Date: 08/20/2021". [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18498254/9245853) using `Variant` also works.